# What is the most optimum why to layout stock tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, inventory

I am building a less than traditional stock system to power a browser/mobile game. Basic principal is a `building` has `stock` of certain `resources`. These `buildings` have an hourly production that decreases imports and produces exports in each building. The productions are based on a `structure` as the type of `building` and that buildings level and capacity.

My dilemma is how to layout out these stock tables in a scalable way. I am able to build tables so that each column is a resources. Example:

```
building_id | structure_id | energy | food | water
--------------------------------------------------
1           | 1            | 459    | 19   | 0
```

The benefit of this method is that I can write a few handy `views` and `events` and power this logic completely from mysql. I can fire one big update statement every hour to transaction productions.

The downfall to this method is that I have to write each resource as a column in my tables. This will be present on my tables in the database as well. I am projecting only have 150 or so resources.

The other option I have been playing with is building this like a basic inventory system. So, having a `stock` table that looks like this:

```
stock_id | building_id | resource_id | qty
-------------------------------------------
1        | 1           | 3           | 19
4        | 1           | 2           | 0
5        | 1           | 1           | 459
```

The benefit to this method is scalabity in to code to allow easy entry of new resources to enhance game play.

The downfall to this method is that I will have to do multiple `UPDATE` and `SELECT` statements to do one `buildings` production. As well as for each `building`. I plan to have a server limit of 250k `buildings`. This can become taxing.

---

All in all, I am looking for the most optimum way of doing this. I will have a finite set of resources and I have the ability to use query building code to create upgrade classes to handle adding a resource. But this also becomes a large set of code to just build the database.

Anyone have any thoughts on this?

---

Edit: 
I am adding how the production sequence works for clarity.

1. the building has to check what it needs to import from stock and how much space it will free up in capacity.
2. the building has to check what it needs to export into stock and how much space it will take up in capacity.
3. building imports and exports are from the `structures` table and are multiplied by the buildings level.
   If we do not exceed capacity and we have all needed resources, the build will transform the stock.

This all, right now runs correctly from one single `UPDATE` statement on all `buildings` and does it quite quick(not tested on sets larger than 100 yet). But this is based on the design with each resource as a column. I can achieve the same structure i do now with a proper inventory system style tables but I would need 150 left joins (there are 150 resources).

Comment: Your second option is the way to go. You are also focusing on performance without taking into account the hardware that will run MySQL server. Since the second option lets you easily add resources, there's no discussion about the data model - it's correct. There is no downfall, if you need to update a lot of data - simply do it, wrap many updates in a single transaction and it will be quick. Selects will also be fast if you properly configure MySQL, and no one prevents you from creating views or materializing tables for performance boost / easier management.

Comment: My max case is 250K buildings. Since the most complex building I built so far is 4 imports and 4 exports, that is 8 resource rows max per building (most are fewer but assume worst case).  so 8 resource rows at 250k buildings is 2mil updates. I would like it run at every hour. If it took 2-3 minutes to complete at maximum capacity, isn't horrible, as look as its ran from a cron task and separate trans per building to prevent hanging while the production is working.

Comment: Are you able to use an SSD instead of mechanical HDD?

Comment: and these are writes to stale data, or "assumed" to be stale data. Haven't determined a particular update is necessary, rather sounds like shot-gun approach

Comment: @N.B. - I would be hosting it with a company.

Comment: Well, a hosting company could have an SSD. Reason I'm asking is - a mechanical drive lets you perform 200-300 IOPS, while an SSD ranges between 10k - 80k iops. Depending on how much data there is to write down, you might easily end up with a few seconds total time to issue entire 2 million updates. Also bear in mind that MySQL won't write to disk if the data didn't change, so that's an extra optimization worth having in mind. At 2 million, on an SSD, using the Event Scheduler (built into MySQL, so you don't need cron), on a dedicated server, we're talking a few seconds, not minutes.

Comment: @DrewPierce - I would be adding `SELECT` statements to the transaction to see if the building production is possible first. I wouldn't waste time sending an `UPDATE` if there isn't anything to update. And what do you mean stale? as in no select being done on that table? I am anticipating this being one of the busier tables.

Comment: @N.B. - wait.. so if mysql does a check before it updates, is it worth checking myself first?

Comment: Not really, you'll just slow it down because it'll do the same job twice for no reason :)

Comment: sounds like you are updating every row (regardless of mysql needing to or not, as it checks, all of which takes time, even if affected rows=0)

Comment: I have to check whether a resource is 'in stock' in order to do the production. I would have to do a couple select statements first in order to check whether it is possible to produce. If it is not possible, it wouldn't update. otherwise the update is necessary.

Comment: If you need 10 of something, but you have 5, if you perform an update - the stock would end up as `-5` - this is where triggers and `SQLSTATE` are useful - you can issue an `SQLSTATE` within after / before update trigger if a column value goes below 0, which is interpreted as an `Exception` in most languages and the query fails, meaning that you're out of stock. Most checks aren't really needed if we use our databases properly.

Comment: This is why I was going to wrap the entire process of checking and update into a stored procedure. Then I can fire one call instead of several. helps eliminate the over of transit time between sql and php/java/etc. Never thought to use triggers this way. Is SQLSTATE just a status code, similar to like the status code returned with an ajax response  (aka includes successes, warnings, errors, and other general notations)

Comment: And on the topic of triggers, should I recycle the zero quantity rows with a trigger to keep the database as slim as possible and assume a missing row is zero. Or should i use the before update where qty is zero delete and interupt the update?

Comment: Here's the [SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/signal.html) syntax (I forgot to mention it's `SIGNAL SQLSTATE` since I just refer to it as `SQLSTATE`). It's a string indicating an error, so you can interpret it similar to HTTP status code, but the docs state you should use `45000`  for user-defined exceptions. I would just use simple logic of having quantities at 0 or more. If a quantity goes below 0, throw an exception (signal sqlstate) and don't update (row is unchanged), which means game won't increase whatever it has to since there's insufficient stock for that action.

Comment: @N.B. - I understand `SQLSTATE`. But I think I might be a little unclear how the game works. basic example, you have a farm. It requires 3 energy and 4 water once an hour to produce 3 food. So my check would have to be if both are in stock, then take them out and put the 3 food in.

Comment: Ok, that means you have an operation that requires 3 updates - first 2 to take two resources and final one to create another resource. You isolate that particular action in a transaction. You try to update the tables and reduce energy / water. If either query fails, the whole thing fails, you issue a signal and roll the transaction back - insufficient resources. If it's successful, you update the quantity of food and commit - job done.

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the 150 resource columns notion. Force joins to behave with index hints after a analyze table xxxx call. 
Verify plan with explain command. Make calls thru stored procs.

I realize this is a game you are constructing. I did large map game play MMOG with such structures items states. The data layer was highly optimized else it woulda barfed the User experience. Lot of memcache.

data is only important as needed. you do not approach a building and fetch every attribute about it. why is that?

```
1) not needed now. who cares that the antenna is blown. it is irrelevant. you are 90 feet from water, how would u use it anyway 
2) slow
3) becomes stale
that is all pull technology. client manually pulls it
```

as for push from server (we had benefit of open socket)
these are critical and need to be near real-time <80ms

```
1) player positions and how equipped
2) base status. this is important. what is where and state in base. these is constantly grabbed by users from mini-maps
3) your player, stats in particular, partly to prevent hacks
these push 90% of the time resided memcached in the structure most friendly to the client side. cannot seem to get anywhere near this performance
```

push: stuff not in memcache but is happening right in front of the player's face. or behind it. like getting shot in the head.

naturally the player isn't pulling that. it independently occurred to walking, zooming.

Obviously of a row with all info without joins is nice. Wasn't suitable for us

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79518/discussion-on-answer-by-asconfused-what-is-the-most-optimum-why-to-layout-stock).

Comment: Well that sucks.. I can't even comment on my own question anymore. I wish I screenshot what was said because I know have none of it. Boo......

Comment: @wesley well it does belong in chat. It is all there in the link. Just continue there

Comment: I can read it but it's impossible to login on mobile.. stack is blocked as a forum at work.. so I am sol.. I agree the 0hp vs jvm discuss should go to chat but your answer does fit all my requirements.. useful information though. I am still looking for a better answer though.

Comment: Stack works but not stack chat url ? Chat is blocked or both are blocked? You were logged in here now to post

Comment: On mobile, when I click the chat link, I get directed out of the stack app and to chrome. Chrome tells me I need to login. So I click login and i get redirected back to the app. Its a loop. At work, I can use a computer to access the internet (ie not a mobile device). But stack is blocked by our network admin. So I am stuck.

Comment: @Wesley u making progress oh inventory guru?

Comment: Some but i need a more thorough understanding of mysql. I am just glad this is a game and not a project with a deadline. I would mind contributors to this if anyone is interested.

Comment: I'd be glad to assist in some way

Comment: Find me on twitter. same handles.